Extract precipitation values from netcfd
I’m stuck on a question about extracting a variable from a NetCDF file. Here is the structure of my input netcdf file:

comephore_all
Out[37]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 85, y: 99, time: 236664)
Coordinates:

x        (x) float64 1.156e+06 1.158e+06 1.158e+06 ... 1.24e+06 1.24e+06
y        (y) float64 5.075e+05 5.065e+05 5.055e+05 ... 4.105e+05 4.095e+05
time     (time) object '1997-01-01 00:00' ... '2023-12-31 23:00'
Data variables:
rr1      (time, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(201600, 99, 85), meta=np.ndarray>
crs      (time) int32 -2147483647 -2147483647 ... -2147483647 -2147483647
Attributes:
title:                     Réanalyse des lames d'eau COMEPHORE
Conventions:               CF-1.6
history:                   Wed Mar 24 13:39:53 2021: ncrcat 1997_rr.nc 19...
nco_openmp_thread_number:  1


I am looking to extract precipitation values for each station into separated .csv files.
I ran an initial test to extract the values for a single station, but it’s very slow. Here is a snippet of the code:
indice_x = 1205500
indice_y = 439500
precip_1205500_439500 = comephore_all.sel(x=indice_x, y=indice_y)
df_precip = precip_1205500_439500.to_dataframe(name='EH')[['EH','date']]
df_precip[['date', 'EH']].to_csv(output_path, index=False)

The issue is not with writing the CSV file but with extracting the precipitation values. The line "df_precip = precip_1205500_439500.to_dataframe(name='EH')[['EH', 'date']]" takes 40 minutes for a single station.
I also tried with dask :
df_precip = precip_1205500_439500.to_dask_dataframe()
df_precip=df_precip[['time', 'rr1']]
df_precip[['time', 'rr1']].to_csv(output_path)

But the line df_precip[['time', 'rr1']].to_csv(output_path)  is taking an infinitely long time to execute.
I think I’m not approaching the extraction of precipitation values correctly.
Thank you for your help!

Hi Lucie, welcome to SO. You should provide more information for others to help you. Can you provide a link to the data from MeteoFrance that you are using?

I think you could make the process faster by skipping the conversion to a DataFrame and directly writing the data into a CSV file.  This could look something like this:
with open(output_path, "w") as f:
    f.write("date,EH\n")
    for i in range(precip_1205500_439500.date.size):
        f.write(f"{precip_1205500_439500.date[i]:f},{precip_1205500_439500.EH[i]:f}\n")

You mentioned that you want to do this for every location, so I assume you will loop over all locations.  In this case, you might want to switch to index-based selecting (using isel or square brackets instead of sel) for even more speed.
I hope this helps to speed up your data extraction.
Cheers,
Markus
